# Problem with random variable elements for Web Scrapping

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I'd like to create a relative function to access every game report available in this table: https://fbref.com/fr/comps/13/calendrier/Scores-et-tableaux-Ligue-1

I started making a relative URL, but there is an element in the URL that I believe to be random.

Here is what I refer to:

- cbdc95fe for: https://fbref.com/fr/matchs/cbdc95fe/Lille-Auxerre-7-Aout-2022-Ligue-1

- 00173ae0 for: https://fbref.com/fr/matchs/00173ae0/Nantes-Lille-12-Aout-2022-Ligue-1

To overcome this limit, do you know efficient ways to open all links within the table?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

using the requests and lxml libraries (lxml for xpath) this becomes a fairly straightforward task:

```
  1 import requests
  2 from lxml import etree
  3 
  4 s = requests.session()
  5 r = s.get("https://fbref.com/fr/comps/13/calendrier/Scores-et-tableaux-Ligue-1")
  6 tree = etree.HTML(r.content)
  7 matchreporturls = tree.xpath('//td[@data-stat="match_report"]/a[text()="Rapport de match "]/@href')
  8 
  9 for matchreport in matchreporturls:
 10     r = s.get("https://fbref.com" + matchreport)
 11     # do something with the response data
 12     print('scraped {0}'.format(r.url))
```